# Changing standard output presentation page size into A4 size?

Tags: beamer, paper-size

I am working on some project and presentations in LaTeX using the `beamer` package. I am just a beginner in this so I really need your help. My problem is that the default presentation page size is small and I need to transform it into A4 paper size. Can anybody help me how to handle this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/3235). The default presentation size in `beamer` is actually A4 but maybe you need portrait orientation rather than landscape, is that so?

Comment: @percusse: No, the default is not A4. It is `5.04in` x `3.78in`, while A4 is `11.69in` x `8.27in` (both in landscape mode).

Comment: @Werner Ah, I am truly losing it. How could I ? I will be in my room for a while. I was thinking about `handout` mode

Comment: Even with the small default page size, most (if not all) PDF viewers can scale the page to more closely fit a standard paper size. I don't think I've ever had a need to explicitly resize a Beamer presentation for printing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Werner's example shows a problem with the `beamer` class, namely that the class doesn't redefine `\frametitle` in `handout` mode, which is really annoying. I always recommend you do something along the following lines. (Alternatively you may write `\frametitle<handout>{...}`, which is really cumbersome.)

```
\newif\ifmybeamer
%\mybeamertrue
\ifmybeamer
    \documentclass[Madrid]{beamer}
\else
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{beamerarticle}

    \makeatletter
    \def\frametitle{%
        \@ifnextchar<%
            {\@frametitle@lt}%
            {\@frametitle@lt<>}%
    }
    \def\@frametitle@lt<#1>#2{}
    \makeatother
\fi

\author{Me}
\title{Beamer Tricks}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%
   \frametitle<notes>{Hi}
   Hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Redefining `\framesubtitle` is done in a similar way.

Comment: This is also another gr8 solution thx. But i have another question. Can i use colored themes (for exam. \usetheme{Madrid}) in article mode using this beamerarticle package ?

Comment: THX Marc...the name of chapter 15 is "Installing LATEX and Friends" (i just want to be sure)?And the reason why i was asking for transformation into A4 is described here :) pls take a look and maybe you can give me some clue.http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39367/using-beamer-and-article-class

Answer (score 14):

Here you can use the options of [`beamerposter`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamerposter) to modify the page size to your needs. `beamerposter` supports `A0`, `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4`, as well as some `custom` formats through its `size` package option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[size=a4]{beamerposter}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is a frame}
  Here is some frame content.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could just add the A4 specifications from `beamerposter` in your [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) presentation preamble:

```
% Format presentation size to A4
\setlength{\paperwidth}{29.7cm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{21.0cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{28.7cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{20.0cm}
```

Note, however, that your presentation font size will be very small compared to that of the regular presentation display, as may be seen from this output of the above MWE (left is A4, right is default):

[image]

Comment: You can also try to change the aspect ratio of the presentation to look like (almost) A4. `\documentclass[aspectratio=149]{beamer}` is a little longer looking than A4.

Comment: This works much better than changing the paper size since it doesn't affect the relative size of the font.