# Colored sectioning - headings

Tags: sectioning, color

I am working on some project in `pdflatex`. I am not an expert in this so I really need your help :). Well what I am trying to do:

- I (or somebody) will make some common `.tex` file (with some text) with regular PDF output using `article` class.
- But I want my `\chapter` , `\title`, `\section`s, `\subsection`s and `\items` to be automatically colored.

Any ideas how can I achieve this effect?

I firstly tried to use just the `beamer` class and `beamerposter.sty` to transform the presentation page into A4 size and keep those colors. But the problem was that I can't see my section and subsection (they are only visible in `\tableofcontents`).

EXAMPLE CODE (and I want this to look a little bit colorful...check out the screenshot)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm,text={17cm, 23cm},top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin {document}

    \begin{center}
    \rm \large \textbf {blabalablabla}
    \vfill 
    \rm \LARGE \textbf {TITLE}\\    
    \rm \large \textbf {(blabla)}
    \vfill 
    \end{center}

\chapter{CHAPTER}

\section{sec1}

    text - in section 1

\section{sec2}      

    text in section 2

    \begin{itemize}
    \item ITEM
    \end{itemize}

\section{sec3}
    \subsection{subsec1}
        \subsubsection{subsubsec1}

\end {document}
```

This is just a simple example to show you what i mean.

[image: This is just a simple example to show you what i mean.]

Comment: Do you have something specific in mind? Do you only need the titles of the sections to be colored or the whole body of them? It would really help if you can provide specific details such that everybody can contribute on different points.

Comment: I answered this in the thread that's entitled *Changing standard output presentation page size into A4 size*

Comment: I have put some more details into my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the following link [Fancy Chapter Headings](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/fancy-chapter-tikz/). It uses TikZ to modifiy the style of the heading, maybe it gives you a starting point. Also have a look at the `titlesec` package which makes it much easier to adjust the sections in TeX.